# How to connect the my SQL db and execute the queries and store to dbtable by using jsr223 sampler which code are written in this sampler? Sample code

Tags: mysql, jmeter

Please give step by step process

How to connect MySQL db and excute queries and stored those results in db table by using jsr223 sampler? Please give sample code this topic

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [MySQL JDBC Driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and drop it to "lib" folder of your JMeter installation (or other folder in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath))
2. Restart JMeter to pick up the .jar
3. Add [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to your Test Plan
4. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Thread Group
5. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.sql.Sql

   def url = 'jdbc:mysql://your-database-host:your-database-port/your-database-name'
   def user = 'your-username'
   def password = 'your-password'
   def driver = 'com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'
   def sql = Sql.newInstance(url, user, password, driver)

   def query= 'INSERT INTO your-table-name (your-first-column, your-second-column) VALUES (?,?)'
   def params = ['your-first-value', 'your-second-value']
   sql.executeInsert query, params

   sql.close()
   ```
6. Change `your-database-host`, `your-database-port`, etc. to real IP address, port, credentials, table name, column name, etc.
7. Enjoy.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Working with a relational database](https://groovy-lang.org/databases.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

---

P.S. I believe using [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler would be way faster and easier

Comment: How the values comes in this ? Places,please give me groovy code in this scenario

Comment: It depends on what do you want to store

Comment: I want store jmeter results generated CSV file  values like samples ,avg ,min,max,errors,90 percent values comes automatically in this ?,and store this values MySQL db,please give this process hole groovy code .reading the CSV/jtl file and those values comes in this ? ,Please give me step by process and code required for me

Comment: samples are in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), other values are **calculated**, if you need them - consider using [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line/).  "Raw" values can be inserted like: `new File('test.csv').readLines().each { line -> sql.executeInsert query 'INSERT INTO your-table VALUES(' + line + ')' }`. With regards to "give me code" - this is [not a code writing service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service)

Comment: Sorry for asking the code, I mean iam asking sample code how to write groovy script ,read the CSV file and how this values comes ? Place

Comment: The sample code to read the file and to insert the lines into the database has been provided already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242292/discussion-between-g-r-and-dmitri-t).